# Which date is true?

Tags: islamic-history, date

I was looking at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Karbala) article about Battle of Karbala:

> The Battle of Karbala (Arabic: مَعْرَكَة كَرْبَلَاء) was fought on **10 October 680** (10 Muharram in the year 61 AH of the Islamic calendar) between the army of the second Umayyad caliph Yazid I (r. 680–683) and a small army led by Husayn ibn Ali, the grandson of the Islamic prophet Muhammad, at Karbala, Sawad (modern-day southern Iraq).

On the other hand in an Iranian [website](https://www.bahesab.ir/time/conversion/) I converted the Islamic date to Gregorian date and the result was **13 October 680**:

[image: Karbala]

Which date is precise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do realize, I hope, that [Gregorian dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) don't exist before 1582. The date difference with the Julian calendar was 11 days in the 1700's; and 11 centuries earlier, skipping the years divisible by 400 (namely 1600, 1200, and 800), the date difference was 11 - (11-3) = 3 days as you have noted.

Also this comment, which I  made earlier below:

***Both*** dates are true. The calendars (Julian and Gregorian) count days differently, which is why the dates are in variance. If you think that is confusing: imagine how life was in English speaking countries between 1582, when the Catholic countries largely adopted the Gregorian calendar, and 4 Sept 1752 when the English speaking countries did. Every letter had to be written with both dates, styled *new* and *old*, in order to be unambiguous.

Comment: So October 13 is true?

Comment: ***Both*** are true. The calendars count days differently, which is why the dates are in variance. If you think that is confusing: imagine how life was in English speaking countries between 1582, when the Catholic countries largely adopted the Gregorian calendar, and 4 Sept 1752 when the English speaking countries did. Every letter had to be written with both dates, styled *new* and *old*, in order to be unambiguous.